# Unix Shell Script to write file name from Directory

Tags: unix

Could you let me now on below.

Example:

In tmp directory below, I have output.txt file, every day I have to look for below .xml files and write the .xml file names into output.txt file (overwrite).

I m using this statement:

```
ls -1 IBM.PPSDSD.INV.* > Output.txt
```

But, how to get above statement into a shell script so that i can give program file to DBAs.

```
/tmp directory
Output.txt
IBM.PPSDSD.INV.20180324150220.xml
IBM.PPSDSD.INV.20180426150220.xml
IBM.PPSDSD.INV.20180729150220.xml
```

Thanks
Aj

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -1 /tmp/IBM.PPSDSD.INV.* > /tmp/Output.txt
```

I have added the path `/tmp/` in two places, so it is not needed that the script is run in the `/tmp` directory.

Takw care which file names you use. You description says `output.txt`, but your example shows `Output.txt`. That are totally different files!